# Can anyone recommend me the some color scheme for my website

Tags: website-design, website-templates

i want to use this color as base color for my site

[image]

I have navigation bar on left which is vertical around  220px wide and 47px height per tab
i also have horizontal navigation tabs as well

Now i am confused what should be the background color of tabs and what should be the hover color and active tab color

Can anyone have some ideas

The site design is simple

```
HEADER
HORIZONTAL NAV BAR
LEFTNAV BAR(left) ---BODY CONTENT(right)
Footer
```

Comment: This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion. Please ask questions about specific issues you are having, even when asking for a review of a specific design, but not general idea-gathering or brainstorming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out Adobe Kuler (pronounced cooler).

Great resource for color schemes / color inspiration. You can even search for "blue".

http://kuler.adobe.com/

Comment: Are any site examples using blue color theme , i wan to see some example. i am confused how to use those colors

Comment: First result in a Google search for "blue websites" - http://www.webdesign.fm/60-awesome-blue-websites/. In Kuler, you would find the blue you liked, then utilize the other colors of the palette as secondary/accent colors (ie: One color for links, one for borders, etc). Kuler palettes help one visualize what colors work well together. You're already sold on blue as a primary color...use Kuler or one of the 60 sites to find a good set of complimentary colors for your project.